Learning Piano/Keyboard
I started 1 year ago learning keyboard -the method being Full chord with prominence for melody note with right hand , and left hand with root note ( with fixing last finger on tonic note ). For eg: if the song shows melody note D in treble clef, I play GBD in RH if the chord name suggest G at top of the treble clef, then use LH with 5th finger on only G  below octave .
My sheet contain only treble clef with Chord note symbol .
The question is is this right way to go forward .


The vertical lines at the edges are a bit odd; I suspect that they're created by some kind of screenshotting/cropping process and we can ignore them.


For eg: if the song shows melody note D in treble clef, I play GBD in RH if the chord name suggest G at top of the treble clef, then use LH with 5th finger on only G below octave.

Yes, that is the basic idea of how to use the chord symbols above the melody staff.
But, you can approach it in "levels" of sophistication for the left hand.
First level could be just playing the chords in "root position", that is, root on bottom, go up in thirds, like chord G, play from lowest bass to highest G B D. Then for the C chord, play C E G, etc.
Second level is to try smooth voice leading between the chords. That idea is move the left hand notes by the fewest number of steps. For example, if the chords are | G | C | D | G |, then smooth voice leading could be G B D, G C E, F# A D, G B D.
Third level is to combine playing the chord root only in the low bass, on the first beat of the chord, then on the second beat of the chord, or some other subsequent beat, play the full chord, or remaining notes of the chord, in a roughly middle range of the piano. Some call this "bass and chord" or "waltz style" accompaniment. Sort of like this:

       D     E     D     B
       B     G     F#    G 
    G     C     D     G

The middle range chord tones can be played roughly around middle C and the bass tones at two octaves below middle C.
There are other ways to elaborate the left hand accompaniment, but three levels is a good starting approach to practice.

Your approach is certainly a valid way to get started playing chords. As you get more used to it, you might make some changes, like using other fingers of the left hand based on what's convenient, or changing the order of the right hand notes.
All that is how to play a chord. Melody is a different idea. At the most basic, "chord" means "playing several notes at once," and "melody" means "playing several notes, but only one at a time." In practice we often combine them. This music notation shows both ideas: the staff notation is the melody, and the letters show chords that go with it.
In describing your approach, you talk about playing the "melody note with the right hand." Maybe that's not the best way of thinking about it. For some of these chord symbols, there's a rest in the melody at the moment the chord is played. And for some, the melody note is one that isn't included in the chord (like the next-to-last chord, a G chord, with an E in the melody). I would encourage you to learn this at first by either playing the melody or the chords. You could, for example, sing the melody while playing the chords, or play along with someone else to put both parts together. If you want to do both parts yourself, it might be simplest to play your three chord notes in the left hand, leaving the right hand free to play single melody notes.

That is one way to approach music that is presented in that particular way - melody plus chord symbols.   You might like to also play some fully-notated piano music, with specific notes for both the right and left hands.
